# Silly question about holding an expression in a sum

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, evaluation

Sorry about this dumb question in advance. Suppose I evaluate this :

```
test[x_, y_] := Laplacian[x^2 + y^2, {x, y}]
test[x, y] /. {x -> 1, y -> 1} (*4*)
```

Now if I try to do :

```
Sumovertest[x_, y_] := Sum[test[x + x^2 k, y + y^2 k ], {k, 0, 1}]

Sumovertest[x, y] /. {x -> 1, y -> 1} (*4 + Laplacian[8,{2, 2}]*)
```

It treats the second variable as a numerical argument. I have tried Holding the form but it does not work. I know this must be super simple.

Comment: This example shows us we should not abuse `:=`: `test[x_, y_] = Laplacian[x^2 + y^2, {x, y}]`

Comment: To be specific, does this answer therein answers your question?: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18487/1871

Comment: @xzczd thanks a lot. I never realized this mistake